# How to properly Pin in Parse localDataStore?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pinning, local-datastore

I have `Parse.enableLocalDatastore()` in my app delegate before `Parse.setApplicationId`

Then I have `var newPosts = PFObject(className: "Post")` as a global variable.

Then I want to get 1,000 latest objects from the "Post" table from localDataStore that I enabled earlier so I do this:

```
var getNewPosts = PFQuery(className: "Post")
getNewPosts.fromLocalDatastore()
getNewPosts.limit = 1000
getNewPosts.orderByDescending("createdAt")
getNewPosts.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (downloadedPosts, error) -> Void in
        if downloadedPosts != nil && error == nil {
            println(downloadedPosts) // I am getting table with no data
        }
    }
```

But I only get empty data rows.
If I comment out the `getNewPosts.fromLocalDatastore()` line results are fine.

I understand that I am missing the critical **Pinning** step but not sure from Parse documentation hoe and where to implement it. Can you please help?

Comment: It sounds like you need to "fetch" the data after findObjects.  Did you ever find a solution to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting no data....
reasons my be...

Wrong name of class (class names are case sensitive)
Data is not there in local storage

Try synchronous version of findObject: method and pin: method.

Comment: I am getting data but is not what it should be. I am getting 
`<Post: 0x17412ed80, objectId: new, localId: local_912c89a17e3dae62> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x170058540>";
},` for each row of data that there is in the table

Comment: Parse object look like...<Person: 0x7a251f50, objectId: LSIWsvAlFL, localId: (null)> {  ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7a24fd80>"; fname = Geeta;    lname = Patel; } In Post object there isn't any property..!! only ACL is there...try to set any property and then check..

Comment: Properties are already set and show when I comment out `getNewPosts.fromLocalDatastore()`